# VisualForce PageBlockTable only Renders Integers, not Decimals. Why?

Tags: visualforce

This is weird...I'm declaring integers and decimal in exactly the same way in custom controller, but the apex:pageBlockTable will only show the integer. Anyone know what's up?

```
Integer OppsOwned = 4;
Decimal Rate = 2.3;

<apex:column value="{! uw.OppsOwned }">
<apex:facet name="header">Total Opps</apex:facet>
</apex:column>
<apex:column value="{! uw.Rate }">
<apex:facet name="header">Conv Rate</apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

OppsOwned integer shows just fine. Rate shows as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was just a slow Dev Console issue! After a while it populated just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This works just fine:

```
public class testPageController {
    public List<FakeObj> fakeObjs {get; set;}

    public testPageController() {
        this.fakeObjs = new List<FakeObj>();

        for (Integer x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            Integer i = Integer.valueOf(Math.random() * 10);
            Decimal d = Math.random() * 10;
            d = d.setScale(2);

            this.fakeObjs.add(new fakeObj(i, d));
        }
    }

    private class FakeObj {
        public Integer testInt {get; set;}
        public Decimal testDec {get; set;}

        public FakeObj(Integer i, Decimal d) {
            this.testInt = i;
            this.testDec = d;
        }
    }
}
```

Page

```
<apex:page controller="testPageController" doctype="html-5.0" tabStyle="test_page__tab">
     <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!fakeObjs}" var="fakeObj">
            <apex:column value="{!fakeObj.testInt}" headerValue="Test Int" />
            <apex:column value="{!fakeObj.testDec}" headerValue="Test Int" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Result:

[image]

That most likely means that your issue is somewhere else in your code, without a more detailed code sample I don't think we can help you.